# componentDidMount not firing in React

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

import Post from './components/Post.jsx';
import Feed from './components/Feed.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      view: 'feed',
      collection: ''
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component did mount')
    this.getCollection();
  }

  async getCollection() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/page');
      const responseJSON = await response.json();

      this.setState({ collection: responseJSON }, () => {
        console.log("App Component - getCollection() State Updated", this.state);
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("App Component - getCollection() error", error);
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       Text
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Can't get component did mount to function. Trying to make an ajax request to my mongodb and render that on the client side. All I need to do now is make a state change setting the collection to the information I get back. I tried using an Ajax request but that didnt work. Now I'm implementing an async fetch call as per the suggestion of another contributor.

the nonworking ajax request:

As of now, componentDidMount is still not being triggered and the collection property of the state is still an empty string.

Comment: You have to bind `getCollection`

Comment: I have the success and error case bound, where else do i need to? I cant get the success console log case to fire

Comment: You need to add a `render` function

Comment: Can you add the entire file's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API for AJAX calls and making use of ES6 [Async/Await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await), since importing an entire library just for Ajax seems a bit overkill.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collection: ''
    }
    this.getCollection = this.getCollection.bind(this)
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component did mount')
    this.getCollection();
  }

  async getCollection() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/blogs');
      const responseJSON = await response.json();

      this.setState({ collection: responseJSON }, () => {
        console.log("App Component - getCollection() State Updated", this.state);
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("App Component - getCollection() error", error);
    }
  }

    render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with your render, but I've left it out. Hopefully, this will shed some light on how best to perform what you want.

Comment: I tried to implement the async getCollection but I get this error: Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (72:15)

Comment: Are you able to link the entire file, in your question.

Comment: I appreciate your help and have implemented your code, componentDidMount is still not being triggered

Comment: How are you using the component? Update the question, with the changes you've made. So I can see completely how you're using it. because it's working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168586/discussion-between-brayheart-and-paul-mcloughlin).

Answer (score 1):

To get `componentDidMount` to fire you need the `render` function. Because first the component renders and then it calls the function componentDidMount.

I think adding this to your class should solve your problem.

```
render() {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have a render return statement. I didn't include it as I dont think the problem lies in there. I think it has something to do with the binding.